# How to activate ANSI shell script colors in Visual Studio Codium terminals?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal, vscodium

I am using Visual Studio Codium on MacOs.

When I open a terminal and enter `echo "\033[31mThis is red font.\033[0m"`I get a nice red text.

When I run a shell script reading

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "\033[31mThis is red font.\033[0m"
```

in the same terminal I get `\033[31mThis is red font.\033[0m`

What can I do to have the shell scripts produce colored text in the terminal window?

Comment: `echo` by itself does not interpret \033. You have to writ `echo -e ...`, so the interesting question is not, why you don't see colours from your script, but why you see colours from the command line. As a first step, I would do a `type echo` on the command line, to see what _echo_  you are using there.

Comment: @user1934428  With `type echo`I get ècho is a shell builtin`. However, you answer already solves my question. When I use `echo -e`it works as expected. If you provide this as an answer I can accept it :-)

Comment: `echo` behavior is not consistent. people would recommend `printf` be used. i personally define `echo` as a function which invokes `printf`.

Comment: @pynexj ... tried that across my tool set and it is even more consistent (I got a few obscure cases where also the echo -e failed). Great help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cause escape sequences to interpreted, the `-e` option can be used:

```
echo -e .....
```

As long as you use the bash-builtin `echo`, this should be portable.